# Eclipse projects and branches/trunk

Tags: eclipse, svn

I already have a repository with the classical structure

```
/branches
  /current
  /beta
/tags
  /1.0
  /2.0
/trunk
```

I would like to switch from my current editor to Eclipse but how many projects should I create ?

- One for the whole repository ?

  But the auto-completion will find multiple occurrences in the /trunk or /branches/* folders.
- One in /trunk and one in each /branches/* ?

  In that case how can I keep the hierarchical structure of the repository in my workspace ? Is there an other solution than :

  - /workspace/trunk
  - /workspace/beta
  - /workspace/current

Thanks.

Comment: Switch to git and your problems go away.  With SVN and Eclipse, you will need to maintain distinct projects for each branch.  One project for the entire repo seems very problematic.

Comment: As I'm not controlling the project, SVN is mandatory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest having a separate eclipse project for the trunk and each of the branches.

I found it's much easier to merge & tag when the branches are separated. Also, updating a single project will take longer than having separated projects as you will have to checkout the new tags you're creating each time.

Another note is that Eclipse is java based. Checking out the entire codebase as a single project will significantly effect your system performance. When the projects are separated, you can just close the branches you're not working.

Answer (score 0):

@aporat has good advice, though sometimes switching workspaces is pretty slow.  I tend to check out multiple branches in the same workspace, overriding he name in te .project file at checkout- usually by appending the branch name.

Be sure to close any copies you're not actively working on- will save resources on your workstation.

I use a mix of thi approach and having 3 to 5 workspaces.